# Can't create an azure function in free subscription plan. It is showing Deployment failed error

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When I tried to create an azure function in a free subscription plan, it returns da message which shows "Deployment Error - Deployment to resource group {resource_name} failed.
Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.".

But on analyzing through web browser's console window I got the following errors.
[image]

Is this a technical issue happening in the portal or this is due to free subscription account?

Comment: Not sure this is the cause. Did you try to deploy your service in South Central US?  Currently there are some warning in that [Data Center](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/)

Comment: This is likely being caused by a current outage situation. Unfortunately nothing that can be resolved on Stack Overflow. The AzureSupport twitter account has been posting updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are currently experiencing an outage in South Central US
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/
[image]

You will want to monitor the Azure Status Page for further updates. Unfortunately we cannot do anything until the problem has been mitigated by engineering.